# Given two strings S and T, return if they are equal when both are typed into empty text editors. # means a backspace character

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, stack

```
Example 1:

Input: S = "ab#c", T = "ad#c"
Output: true
Explanation: Both S and T become "ac".
Example 2:

Input: S = "ab##", T = "c#d#"
Output: true
Explanation: Both S and T become "".
Example 3:

Input: S = "a##c", T = "#a#c"
Output: true
Explanation: Both S and T become "c".
Example 4:

Input: S = "a#c", T = "b"
Output: false
Explanation: S becomes "c" while T becomes "b".
```

```java
class Solution {
    public boolean backspaceCompare(String S, String T) {

        Stack<Character> stack1 = new Stack<Character>();
        Stack<Character> stack2 = new Stack<Character>();
        for(int i=0;i<S.length();i++){


            if(S.charAt(i)!='#'){
            stack1.push(S.charAt(i));

        }else{
                    stack1.pop();
                }
        }
        for(int j =0;j<T.length();j++){

            if(T.charAt(j)!='#'){
            stack2.push(S.charAt(j));

        }else 
                stack2.pop();
        }

        if(stack1==stack2)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

my output is false and answer should be true why is this not working?

Comment: Why are you pushing character before the `if`?

Comment: BTW, you should create function to normalize the string instead of repeating code for each input.

Comment: And also, `if (cond) return true; else return false;` can simply be `return cond;`

Comment: Code is very difficult to read, and very easy to misinterpret, given the horrendous indentations. Please edit the code and fix that.

Comment: Your output is false because `if(stack1==stack2)` will never be true. Compare using `equals()`, not `==`, i.e. `return stack1.equals(stack2);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first mistake is pushing all the characters on the stack outside of the if statement.

Also you should check if stack is empty before removing items from it.
Otherwise EmptyStackException is thrown.

```
// stack1.push(S.charAt(i)); <-- remove this line
if (S.charAt(i)!='#') {
   stack1.push(S.charAt(i));
}else if (!stack1.isEmpty()) { // <-- add this check
   stack1.pop();
}
```

The second mistake is you can't use == to compare the contents of two stacks, use .equals method instead:

```
if(stack1.equals(stack2))
```

Comment: Runtime Error Messagejava.util.EmptyStackException
  at line 102, java.base/java.util.Stack.peek
  at line 84, java.base/java.util.Stack.pop
  at line 13, Solution.backspaceCompare
  at line 57, __DriverSolution__.__helper__
  at line 87, __Driver__.main
Last executed input:
"a##c"
"#a#c"

Comment: https://leetcode.com/explore/featured/card/30-day-leetcoding-challenge/529/week-2/3291/

Comment: Yes backspace in a text field that's already empty does nothing - you need to add one extra check for that, see the update

Comment: Runtime Error Message:
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 8
  at line 48, java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt
  at line 709, java.base/java.lang.String.charAt
  at line 19, Solution.backspaceCompare
  at line 57, __DriverSolution__.__helper__
  at line 87, __Driver__.main
Last executed input:
"xywrrmp"
"xywrrmu#p"

Comment: Your second loop reads characters from S, should be T: `stack2.push(S.charAt(j))`

Answer (score 1):

[Answer by Joni](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61119863/5221149) correctly addresses the errors in the code, however there are some other issues I'd like to address:

- You should use a helper method to eliminate repeating the same code.
- You should use [`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) instead of [`Stack`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html). The javadoc says so.
- Instead of using `Stack`/`Deque`, I'd recommend using `StringBuilder`, to prevent having to box the `char` values.

Something like this:

```
public boolean backspaceCompare(String s, String t) {
    return applyBackspace(s).equals(applyBackspace(t));
}

private static String applyBackspace(String s) {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (s.charAt(i) != '#')
            buf.append(s.charAt(i));
        else if (buf.length() != 0)
            buf.setLength(buf.length() - 1);
    }
    return buf.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your idea works, but it's expensive and unnecessary to copy the strings into stacks.  If you work backwards from the end, no extra storage is necessary:

```
//given the string length or a valid character position, return
//the position of the previous valid character, or -1 if none
public static int previousCharPos(String s, int pos)
{
    int bs=0; // number of backspaces to match
    while(pos>0) {
        --pos;
        if (s.charAt(pos)=='#') {
            ++bs;
        } else if (bs <= 0) {
            return pos;
        } else {
            --bs;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

public static boolean backspaceCompare(String S, String T)
{
    int spos = previousCharPos(S,S.length());
    int tpos = previousCharPos(T,T.length());
    while(spos >= 0 && tpos >= 0) {
        if (S.charAt(spos) != T.charAt(tpos)) {
            return false;
        }
        spos = previousCharPos(S,spos);
        tpos = previousCharPos(T,tpos);
    }
    return spos == tpos;
}
```