# ERROR: AddressSanitizer: negative-size-param: (size=-1)

Tags: c++, address-sanitizer

Sorry for this messy code, but I have a question.

I tried to solve a LeetCode's 844 task. Its given that

> Given two strings S and T, return if they are equal when both are typed into empty text editors. # means a backspace character.

**1st Example**

> Input: S = "ab#c", T = "ad#c"
>   Output: true
>   Explanation: Both S and T become "ac".

**2nd Example**

> Input: S = "ab##", T = "c#d#"
>   Output: true
>   Explanation: Both S and T become "".

My solution here:

```
class Solution {
public:
    bool backspaceCompare(string S, string T) {
        vector<char> a;
        vector<char> b;
        int id = 0; 
        for(int i = 0; i < S.length(); i++){
            a.push_back(S[i]);
            id++;
            if(S[i]=='#'){
                a.erase(a.begin()+id-2);
                id--;
                a.erase(a.begin()+id-1);
                id--;
            }
            if(S[i+1]=='#'){
                a.erase(a.begin()+id-1);  
                id--;
                i+=2;
            } 
        }id = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < T.length(); i++){  
            b.push_back(T[i]);
            id++;
            if(T[i]=='#'){
                b.erase(b.begin()+id-2);
                id--;
                b.erase(b.begin()+id-1);
                id--;
            }
            if(T[i+1]=='#'){
                b.erase(b.begin()+id-1);
                i+=2;
            }
        }
        bool x;
        if(a.size()==0) x = true;
        else{
            for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++){
                if(a[i]==b[i]) x = true;
                else x = false;
            }
        }return x;
    }
};
//Input: S = "ab##", T = "c#d#"
```

*Runtime Error Message*

> =================================================================
>   ==32==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: negative-size-param: (size=-1)
>       #8 0x7f585c70d82f  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x2082f)
>   0x602000000151 is located 0 bytes to the right of 1-byte region [0x602000000150,0x602000000151)
>   allocated by thread T0 here:
>       #5 0x7f585c70d82f  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x2082f)
>   ==32==ABORTING

But it gives me such an error. I think that everything fine here with size. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Lets say `#` is the first character of the string, what is your code going to do?

Comment: [Java version of the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61119616/given-two-strings-s-and-t-return-if-they-are-equal-when-both-are-typed-into-emp).

Comment: You should create function to simplify the string, instead of duplicate logic.

Comment: @NathanOliver But my code is failing at this ("ab##" "c#d#") case.

Comment: Your comparison function is also wrong as x relies only on  last character comparison. `return a == b;` should do the job.

Comment: Out of bound access with `S[i+1]`.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: @NathanOliver Ok, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several issues in your code

```
int id = 0; 

for (int i = 0; i < S.length(); i++){
    a.push_back(S[i]);
    id++;
    if (S[i]=='#'){
        a.erase(a.begin()+id-2);
        id--;
        a.erase(a.begin()+id-1);
        id--;
    }
    if(S[i+1]=='#'){
        a.erase(a.begin()+id-1);  
        id--;
        i+=2;
    } 
}
```

- You don't handle `'#'`as first character (or extra `'#'`).
- `S[i+1]` is out of bound when `i == S.size() - 1`
- your `i += 2` is done in addition to the regular `++i`.

Your code can be simplified with:

```
std::string backspace_string_simplification(const std::string& s)
{
    std::string res;

    for (char c : s) {
        if (c != '#') {
            res.push_back(c);   
        } else if (!res.empty()) {
            res.pop_back();   
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b43bb61cb4287b14)

Then, your "string comparison":

```
bool x;
if (a.size() == 0)
    x = true;
else {
    for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        if(a[i]==b[i]) x = true;
        else x = false;
    }
}
return x;
```

- when `a` is empty, string are equal if `b` is empty too.
- if size of `a` and `b` differs, you have either out of bound access in the loop, or ignore remaining comparison (whereas it should be false).
- your `if` in the loop is equivalent to `x = (a[i] == b[i])`, so your loop is equivalent to (with correct size) `x = a.back() == b.back()`.

You can simply do `return a == b;` (either `std::string` and `std::vector<char>` handle that).

resulting in

```
bool backspaceCompare(string lhs, string rhs) {
    return backspace_string_simplification(lhs) == backspace_string_simplification(rhs);
}
```